# Usage of adding please to a "do you" question?

Tags: usage

I know that "please" is normally used with "may" or "can" ("May/Can I have this book, please?), but can "please" also be used when asking for information? For instance, is "Do you have this book in stock, please?" correct and idiomatic?

Comment: Yes, it's fine to add it to a request for information.

Comment: It's often used if you're asking for something ("Do you have this book in stock?" implies "and can I get a copy if you do have it?") but it might also be used out of politeness ("Do you know when the next train is, please?")

Comment: @KateBunting Maybe this is another US/UK split, but I don't find that adding *please* to a request for information sounds very natural in US English.  We tend to only add it to requests for actions/objects, e.g. "Hand me that book, please" or "Sit down, please."